# Why error message "TypeError: expressJwt is not a function" is appearing? How can it be fixed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authorization, token, express-jwt

jwt.js:

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt')

function authJwt() {
    const secret = process.env.secret
    return expressJwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256']
    })
}

module.exports = authJwt
```

terminal:

```
C:\code-wldn\final-project\wldn-api\helpers\jwt.js:5
return expressJwt({
       ^

TypeError: expressJwt is not a function
    at authJwt (C:\code-wldn\final-project\wldn-api\helpers\jwt.js:5:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code-wldn\final-project\wldn-api\app.js:18:9)
```

I tried to resolve the error message

> TypeError: expressJwt is not a function

by ensuring that express-jwt is properly imported and used as a function in the jwt.js file. I expected the error to be resolved, allowing the application to run without any issues related to expressJwt. However, the error persisted despite my attempts to address it.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to destructure it?

Comment: I'm just learning JWT, and I'm stuck on how to solve it

Comment: It’s not about using jwts. It’s more about using that library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per express-jwt [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt#usage) says, it should be imported using the following syntax:

```
var { expressjwt } = require("express-jwt");
```

Comment: still can not, TypeError: expressJwt is not a function

Comment: Which version of node are you using? Have you tried importing the function using ES6 syntax? `import { expressjwt } from "express-jwt";`

Comment: node --version
v20.11.0

Comment: There is a typo it isn't expressJwt it is expressjwt

Answer (score 0):

Since you are importing the whole module, you have to specify the method to use. For example:

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

function authJwt() {
    const secret = process.env.secret;

    return expressJwt.expressjwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256'],
    })
  }
```

resources:By @ChocoNao